# Automatically Add Table Row after 5 Table Columns with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

This has eluded me.

As the title states, I have a table with X (constantly changing) amounts of data in it.

To make things easier I am after a bit of Javascript code I can inject which will automatically add the  tag after every 5th `<td>` tag. (Ideally I'd also want the auto TR tags to have a set height with them too.

Any help anyone can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, what is this 'tag'??? :-p
Anyways,
 Take this:-

```
function retHtml(data)// n is number of items
 {
     var n=data.length;
    var html='';
    var n_i=0;
    var i=0;
    for(n_i=0;n_i<n;n_i++)
    {
       i=i%5; //you asked 5
        if(i==0) html+='<tr style="height:40px">';
       html+='<td>' + data[n_i] +'</td>';
       if(i==4) html+='</tr>'
       i++; //make i 5, it will become zero in next iteration!
    }
    if(i<5 & html!='') html+='</tr>';
    return html;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't paying enough attention when I posted the question and as such had my code stripped.

The 'tag' was the TR tag to be added after every 5th TD.

I'm not having the easiest job getting this code to work, I think my knowledge is lacking. Would it be possible to get in a jsfiddle? Or a bit of an instruction on how to include this please?

Comment: You are welcome. Well, I have modified the code a bit. Now, you have to just pass the array and 'n' will be calculated by data.length! Also, for tr height, I have added style attribute. Alternatively, you could create a css class(say mytr) and instead of html+='<tr style="height:40px">' you could have html+='<tr class="mytr">'.
For jsfiddle, follow this:-
in HTML section, type: <table id='tt'></table>
in javascript section:-
var data=['j','k','l','m','n','o']; //Anything what your data contains
document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML=retHtml(data); //tt is our table
 + the function